# NextJS: link button with onClick handler to top-level dynamic route

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing, app-router

How would one go about linking a button element to a top-level [dynamic route](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes), using:

- NextJS 13.4.9 (using App Router)
- React/dom 18.2.0

My directory structure is as follows:

```
app/
- [division]
- - page.tsx
- - [team]
- - - page.tsx
- - - [player]
- - - - page.tsx
```

Example `app/[division]/page.tsx`:

```
// app/[division]/page.tsx

export default function Page({ params }: { params: { division: string } }) {
  return <div>My Division {params.division}</div>;
}
```

From my understanding after [reading the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#userouter-hook), the recommended way to go about his would be to `import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'` and use it in the `onClick` handler, where the button is. For example:

```
// app/page.tsx

'use client'
 
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()
 
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => router.push('/example')}>
      Example
    </button>
  )
}
```

In this example, the `push` method expects a string.

But from my understanding, I'd want something like:

`router.push({ division: 'northwest' })`

And deeper links would look like this:

`router.push({ division: 'northwest', team: 'otters', player: 'sammy-slapstick' })`

The `push` method doesn't allow url objects, like the [Page Router useRouter function](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#with-url-object) does.

So, **how do I link from a button to top-level (and deeper) dynamic links?**

Note, this is the ONLY (top-level) dynamic link in my application.

Other stuff:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791374

I attempted to add `onClick={() => router.push({ division: "northwest" })`, but this didn't work.

Comment: If the button works like a link, you should be using next/link instead.

Comment: Thanks @Terry, I tend to agree. However even their examples (pasted above in my OP) use the `onClick()` handler in a button element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object with `push`

See https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#with-url-object

```
// app/page.tsx

'use client'
 
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()
 
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => {
        router.push({
          pathname: 'app/[division]/page',
          query: { division: whateverTheIdOrSlugIs },
        })
      }}
    >
      Example
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: The links and examples you provided were for the Page Router.


This doesn't work in the App Router - the element won't even render.


`TS2345: Argument of type '{ pathname: string; query: { division: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

Comment: To add to my comment above, the `useRouter` for `next/navigation` only accepts strings, not objects as well like the `next/router` `useRouter` does.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router